# ssrs hyperlink to other report as PDF or excel

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create a hyperlink on  SSRS report data and when clicked opens a separate PDF/excel file of other report using some parameters from current report.

```
Column1 | column2 | Column3

Link1     Link2     Link3  
Link1     Link2     Link3
```

Actually I designed two reports from first report data should have hyperlink while click on that pass parameter to second report but the second should be open a seperate pdf/excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the URL Access Parameter Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)

Your url will look something like

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer/MyFolder/MyReport&RptParam=ParamValue&Format=PDF
```

If you need to do this dynamically, use an expression to populate the format and the parameter value in the url for the action. Your url expression might look like:

```
="http://myrshost/ReportServer/MyFolder/MyReport&RptParam=" & Fields!RptParam.Value & "&Format=PDF"
```

Instead of PDF you can use EXCEL if that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I use go to url concept, I need to change dynamically the 'myrshost-QC/Reportserver' or 'myrshost-UAT/Reportserver'. How to make this possible

Comment: There is a global variable for ReportServerUrl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255216.aspx